# Access to mic permission prompt issue with Mediarecorder in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc, mediarecorder

I wrote some code for recording audio in browser with MediaStreamRecorder.  It records and then posts a audio tag with the recorded audio to the DOM.  In chrome, everything works, except the prompt to permit use of the microphone won't go away once you click allow.  In firefox, the prompt goes away, but the audio tag doesn't successfully append to the DOM.  Can someone give me some advice?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    var mediaConstraints = { audio: true };
    var mediaRecorder;
    var formData;
    var spinner = "<div id='bouncers'><div class='double-bounce1'></div><div class='double-bounce2'></div></div>";
     $('#start-recording').on('click', function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
});

     $('#stop-recording').on('click', function() {
    this.disabled = true;
         $('#start-recording').prop('disabled', false);
         $('#submit-recording').prop('disabled', false);
         $('.spinner').find('#bouncers').remove();
         mediaRecorder.stop();
         audio.controls = true;
         console.log($('audio'));
         $('#audiocontainer').append(audio);
    });

     $('#submit-recording').on('click', function() {
         $.ajax({
             url: $('#posturl').data('posturl'),
             data: formData,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             type: 'POST'
         });
     });

     function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
          $('#start-recording').prop('disabled', true);
          $('#stop-recording').prop('disabled', false);
         mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
         mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/ogg';
         $('.spinner').prepend(spinner);
         mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
             this.stop();
             audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
             formData = new FormData();
             formData.append('recitation[recording]', blob);
         };
         var timeInterval = 30 * 1000;
         mediaRecorder.start(timeInterval);
         $('#stop-recording').disabled = false;
     }

     function onMediaError(e) {
         console.error('media error', e);
     }

     // below function via: http://goo.gl/B3ae8c
    function bytesToSize(bytes) {
        var k = 1000;
        var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
        if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';
        var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k)),10);
        return (bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toPrecision(3) + ' ' + sizes[i];
     }

     // below function via: http://goo.gl/6QNDcI
     function getTimeLength(milliseconds) {
         var data = new Date(milliseconds);
         return data.getUTCHours()+" hours, "+data.getUTCMinutes()+" minutes and "+data.getUTCSeconds()+" second(s)";
     }

     window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        document.querySelector('#start-recording').disabled = false;
     };
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The first is a general browser security issue. On http, you'll always be reprompted. On https, the choice is presented once and the answer remembered.

The second is a general browser compatibility issue, where Firefox and Chrome work differently for a spec that is still in draft, after years. Firefox's supported calls and demonstrator code can be found over at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API/Using_the_MediaRecorder_API